# Change wording of pagination information in jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

This may have already been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer. I am looking to change the wording of the footer of a jQuery datatable where it says "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries" to simply be "0 entries". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following bit of code... I wanted it to be dynamic, not just display 0. Sorry about the confusion.

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$('.dataTables_info').html(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay() + ' entries');
```

Comment: Its usefull for change _TOTAL_ in datatable.info() after ajax delete or add record without reload the page .

Answer (score 7):

As of v1.10, you can use the [language configuration](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option, e.g.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "language": {
    "info": "_TOTAL_ entries",
    "infoEmpty": "0 entries"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this? haven't test yet.

```
if(resultData.length == 0){
    $('.dataTables_info').html('0 entries');
}
```